# Can I use the Google Market without syncing other Google data?

Tags: google-play-store, contacts, htc-wildfire

I have HTC Wildfire phone. I want to access Google Market, but I don't want to import any data from my Google Account.

I don't want contacts or any other data from my Google Account on my phone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shut off sync (`Settings -> Accounts and sync -> Auto-sync`).  You should also click on the actual account (in the same settings menu) and uncheck the various things that can be synced.  Alternatively, you could create a second Google account and keep it free of an extraneous information.

Comment: will that work, or do I need to check / uncheck other settings too

Comment: Yep, if it never syncs the data then the data won't be on your phone.  If it syncs something before you shut it off, just clear the data for the relevant app (`Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`). And obviously don't open the GMail app or whatever, at least not with the account in question.