# Enforcing no synchronization with Google

Tags: sync, calendar, google-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use the Google Market without syncing other Google data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8025/can-i-use-the-google-market-without-syncing-other-google-data)

Hello,

I'd like to setup a personal calendar with Funambol's syncing application. My goal is to never let my calendar items go on Google servers, for privacy reasons. But I do have Google Calendar application (from a stock ROM, so not easily uninstallable).

From what I understand, Funambol Sync Client synchronizes with a system-wide calendar, the same which is used by Google Calendar client. Will this make my items sync with remote Google Calendar if I launch Google's client (f.e. by mistake)?

I still want to use Google account for Market--and only for it. How can I enforce a no-synchronization rule only for calendar items?

I think I could remove `/system/app/Calendar.apk` (my phone is rooted), but doesn't Google services synchronize using GTalkService?

Comment: I'm tackling the same problem, but from a different approach. Some of the available calendar applications are too good to avoid using, so I am looking at [rooting & firewalling](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24726/can-google-services-be-firewall-filtered-market-yes-sync-no) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just turn off sync in `Settings -> Accounts and sync`.  You can specifically turn off Calendar syncing for a particular account in that menu, as well.

Comment: I don't see how can I turn off Calendar syncing only. In `Account and sync` there is `Auto-sync` checkbox to control syncing globally and my Google account entry. When I tap my account, there is only `Sync Contacts`, `Sync Gmail` and `Sync Calendar`, which allow to sync manually.

Comment: I see no checkbox there. Just a text `Touch to sync now` with each entry. This is a Motorola Milestone with stock 2.1 ROM.

Comment: The option definitely exists in 2.2 & 2.3 - might be worth thinking about installing a custom ROM?